# Why is gcc evaluating floating point fractional #defines as zero?

Tags: gcc

How is `(float)_micron_to_meter` equal to zero? Given:

```
//convert microns to meters via multiplication
#define _micron_to_meter (1 / 1000000)
```

And yet

```
printf("factor: %f\n", (float)_micron_to_meter);
```

prints out 0.000000.

Oh.. duh... I can't believe I forgot this. Answer below. I hesitate to post this, but I did pretty extensive searches here and couldn't find any other post about it. And there must be some other programmer who will be as clueless as I was being here. If you find another, feel free to mark this as a duplicate, but check why that post wasn't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to any future C programmers (and I /knew/ this, I'm not sure how I missed it). If you have a fractional define, made up of integers, e.g.

```c
//convert microns to meters via multiplication
#define _micron_to_meter (1 / 1000000)
```

then the value is zero.  It's already zero before it makes it out of the (). Because 1 is assumed to be an integer, and (int)1 divided by anything greater than 0 is less than 1 and integers can only go to 0 from 1. If you do this:

```c
#define _micron_to_meter (1.0 / 1000000)
```

Then it works as expected, because 1.0 is assumed to be floating point.